# How does ApplicationContextAware work in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

In spring, if a bean implements `ApplicationContextAware`, then it is able to access the `applicationContext`. Therefore it is able to get other beans.
e.g.

```
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;     

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
      applicationContext = context;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
      return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then `SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext.getBean("name")` can get the bean "name".

To do this, we should put this `SpringContextUtil` inside the `applications.xml`, e.g.

```
<bean class="com.util.SpringContextUtil" />
```

Here the bean `SpringContextUtil` doesn't include the property `applicationContext`. I guess when spring bean initialize, this property is set. But how is this done? How does the method `setApplicationContext` get called?

Comment: Spring is Magic. Embrace the magic

Answer (score 111, accepted):

When spring instantiates beans, it looks for a couple of interfaces like `ApplicationContextAware` and `InitializingBean`. If they are found, the methods are invoked. E.g. (very simplified)

```
Class<?> beanClass = beanDefinition.getClass();
Object bean = beanClass.newInstance();
if (bean instanceof ApplicationContextAware) {
    ((ApplicationContextAware) bean).setApplicationContext(ctx);
}
```

Note that in newer version it may be better to use annotations, rather than implementing spring-specific interfaces. Now you can simply use:

```
@Inject // or @Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is what I want! Maybe I need to read some spring code to understand how spring works.

Comment: It is better to use @Autowired for most of the cases but there are others where that may not work, for example when you have a "@Component" that is a singleton but you need to inject a bean that has a session scope. As the dependencies are autowired in application context creation you won't really have a session bean injected, by having a reference to the application context you can retrieve the session bean programmatically which will return the session bean instance correctly.

Comment: I would expect Spring injects a dynamically generated proxy class instead - such a class has application scope, but when accessed, it delegates to a session scope instance, or throws an exception it there is no request bound to the currently running thread

Comment: @raspacorp if a sesson scope bean cannot be got from injected `ApplicationContext`, then it cannot be got from `ApplicationContextAware instance` either. Because `ApplicationContextAware instance` gets a bean from the same `applicationContext` object as the one injected.

Answer (score 12):

**Spring source code to explain how  ApplicationContextAware work**
when you use `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");`
In `AbstractApplicationContext` class,the `refresh()` method have the following code:

```
// Prepare the bean factory for use in this context.
prepareBeanFactory(beanFactory);
```

enter this method,`beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(new ApplicationContextAwareProcessor(this));` will add ApplicationContextAwareProcessor to AbstractrBeanFactory.

```
protected void prepareBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        // Tell the internal bean factory to use the context's class loader etc.
        beanFactory.setBeanClassLoader(getClassLoader());
        beanFactory.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver(beanFactory.getBeanClassLoader()));
        beanFactory.addPropertyEditorRegistrar(new ResourceEditorRegistrar(this, getEnvironment()));
        // Configure the bean factory with context callbacks.
        beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(new ApplicationContextAwareProcessor(this));
...........
```

When spring initialize bean in `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory`,
in method `initializeBean`,call `applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization` to implement the bean post process. the process include inject the applicationContext.

```
@Override
    public Object applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(Object existingBean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        Object result = existingBean;
        for (BeanPostProcessor beanProcessor : getBeanPostProcessors()) {
            result = beanProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(result, beanName);
            if (result == null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

when BeanPostProcessor implement Objectto execute the postProcessBeforeInitialization method,for example `ApplicationContextAwareProcessor` that added before.

```
private void invokeAwareInterfaces(Object bean) {
        if (bean instanceof Aware) {
            if (bean instanceof EnvironmentAware) {
                ((EnvironmentAware) bean).setEnvironment(this.applicationContext.getEnvironment());
            }
            if (bean instanceof EmbeddedValueResolverAware) {
                ((EmbeddedValueResolverAware) bean).setEmbeddedValueResolver(
                        new EmbeddedValueResolver(this.applicationContext.getBeanFactory()));
            }
            if (bean instanceof ResourceLoaderAware) {
                ((ResourceLoaderAware) bean).setResourceLoader(this.applicationContext);
            }
            if (bean instanceof ApplicationEventPublisherAware) {
                ((ApplicationEventPublisherAware) bean).setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationContext);
            }
            if (bean instanceof MessageSourceAware) {
                ((MessageSourceAware) bean).setMessageSource(this.applicationContext);
            }
            if (bean instanceof ApplicationContextAware) {
                ((ApplicationContextAware) bean).setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization, should if `(result == null)` be `if (result != null)` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified of the ApplicationContext that it runs in.

above is excerpted from the Spring doc website https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html.

So, it seemed to be invoked when Spring container has started, if you want to do something at that time.

It just has one method to set the context, so you will get the context and do something to sth now already in context I think.

Answer (score -1):

ApplicationContextAware Interface ,the current application context, through which you can invoke the spring container services. We can get current applicationContext instance injected by below method in the class

```
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException.
```