# Spring Application context is null in a ApplicationContextAware class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting NullPointerException inside an `ApplicationContextAware` class and I am not sure why. 
Why is the `applicationContext` null on calling `getBean(SomeClass.class)` method

Following is my BeanProviderUtil class:

```
@Component
public class BeanProviderUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        BeanProviderUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

On calling function

```
SomeOtherClass obj = BeanProviderUtil.getBean(SomeOtherClass.class)
```

I am getting NPE. On debugging, it comes out that applicationContext is not properly initialized by Spring.

**Note**

Is it because I have enabled lazy bean initialization?

However, I tried disabling lazy initialization by `@Lazy(false)` as well as from Global `application.yml`, but it didn't help.

Comment: it's a static variable, and you never assign a value to it.

Comment: How can I autowire application context in a static variable?

Comment: @Stultuske I am using exact same code as accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985189/spring-application-context-is-null I need to make the method and variable static. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Stultuske even static variables can be Autowired, hence making applicationContext was not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was going wrong here by Myself.
I have set global lazy Initialization and that was the main culprit.
Since I was not Autowiring `BeanProviderUtil`, the bean was never created and hence `applicationContext` never got initialized.

Setting `@Lazy(false)` fixes the issue.

Earlier, on disabling @Lazy using `@Lazy(false)` it was not working because somehow Spring was not recognizing the `BeanProviderUtil` a component. Adding `@ComponentScan` to my test class does the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, completely forgot that I put the lazy initialization for all my beans and I was wondering why my context were always null

Comment: I have the same problem, I have set `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` in `application.properties`, and in my `ApplicationContextProvider` implementing `ApplicationContextAware` the  `ApplicationContext` is always null. I want to initialize the beans lazily. How do I go about it?