# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException when call JpaRepository from normal class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm a new Java developer. I call a JpaRepository from normal class ( not main, not in controller,..) and get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.wecommit.criticalService.controller.TableSpaceWarningCRC.doTransData(TableSpaceWarningCRC.java:34)
```

Here my code:
normal class:

```
    package com.wecommit.criticalService.critical;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.wecommit.criticalService.entity.HistoryUpload;

public class CreateDataPerTable {

    HistoryUpload historyUpload;
    int l_historyUpload;

    @Autowired
    TableSpaceWarningCRC tableSpaceWarning;
    //Constructor
    public CreateDataPerTable(TableSpaceWarningCRC tableSpaceWarning) {
    }

    public void setHistoryUpload(HistoryUpload historyUpload) {
        //Get time_upload in historyUpload by historyUploadID

        this.historyUpload = historyUpload;
        l_historyUpload = historyUpload.getId();
    }   

    public void creatDataTables() {
//the error row bellow
            tableSpaceWarning.setTableSpaceWarningCRC(historyUpload);
            tableSpaceWarning.doTransData();


    }

}
```

And the class call JpaRepository method:

```
package com.wecommit.criticalService.critical;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.wecommit.criticalService.entity.TableSpace;
import com.wecommit.criticalService.repository.TableSpaceRepository;
import com.wecommit.criticalService.entity.HistoryUpload;

@Component
public class TableSpaceWarningCRC {
    HistoryUpload historyUpload;

    @Autowired
    TableSpaceRepository tableSpaceRepository;

        public TableSpaceWarningCRC() {
    }

    public void setTableSpaceWarningCRC(HistoryUpload historyUpload) {
        this.historyUpload = historyUpload;
    }
    public void doTransData() {
        //TableSpace Data
        List<TableSpace> listTableSpace;
        listTableSpace = tableSpaceRepository.findByLogFileId(historyUpload.getLogFileId());
            for (int i = 0; i < listTableSpace.size(); i++) {
                TableSpaceWarningCreateTableData tableSpaceWarningCreateTableData = new TableSpaceWarningCreateTableData(listTableSpace.get(i),historyUpload.getLogFileId());
            }
    }
}
```

I added many notation but it does not work. Please help me.
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

Your class TableSpaceWarningCRC doesn't seem to be a spring bean. Auto wiring only works inside spring managed classes.

Try adding an @Component annotation on top of the TableSpaceWarningCRC class and then instantiate that class from the application context instead of calling the constructor.

[How to get bean using application context in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088780/how-to-get-bean-using-application-context-in-spring-boot/38274721)

Also, by default spring beans are singletons. So if your class is stateful or requires multiple instances use the prototype scope in the bean definition

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton

Comment: Hey DroidX86, i fix my code folow:
@Autowired
 TableSpaceWarningCRC tableSpaceWarning;
And call methods:
//but i got the same error in row below
   tableSpaceWarning.setTableSpaceWarningCRC(historyUpload);
   tableSpaceWarning.doTransData();
And the class contain Jpa, i add Component notation and fix: 

public TableSpaceWarningCRC() {
 }
 
 public void setTableSpaceWarningCRC(HistoryUpload historyUpload) {
  this.historyUpload = historyUpload;
 }
Please help me.

Comment: Can you edit the question with your fixes. It's hard to see code in the comments

Comment: Hi DroidX86, i have updated my post. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the same line?

Comment: hi, i'm sorry. I have noted the error row. It is at normal class when call TableSpaceWarningCRC method.

Comment: That's because of the same reason but for the CreateDataPerTable  class. That's not a spring-managed bean either. Make that a bean and then the other class should be autowired into it

Comment: hi, i try to create bean for class  by many ways. But service do not start. Maybe, i must write project by another way. Although, thank you very much DroidX86. Have a nice day!