# Retrieving beans in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I've worked with legacy Spring in the past. We defined our beans via xml configuration and manually wired them. My team is finally making a concerted effort to update to annotations and use Spring Boot instead of the 'traditional' approach with Spring MVC.

With that said, I cannot figure out how the heck I retrieve a bean in Boot. In legacy, Spring would either use constructor/setter injection (depending on our configuration), or we could directly call a bean with `context.getBean("myBeanID");` However, it does not appear to be the case anymore.

I put together a small test case to try and get this working in the below code:

```
package com.ots;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GriefUIApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GriefUIApplication.class, args);

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(GriefRecord.class).addAnnotatedClass(RecordId.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(CrossReferenceRecord.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        Statics.setSessionFactory(factory);

        TennisCoach tCoach = new TennisCoach();
        tCoach.getCoach();

    }

}



interface Coach{
    public String workout();
}


@Service
class TennisCoach implements Coach{

    private Coach soccerCoach;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;


    public TennisCoach() {

    }

    public Coach getCoach() {

        System.out.println(context + " IS THE VALUE OF THE CONTEXT OBJECT");

        soccerCoach = (SoccerCoach)context.getBean("soccerCoach");

        System.out.println(soccerCoach.getClass());

        return soccerCoach;

    }

    @Override
    public String workout() {
        String practice = "practice your backhand!";
        System.out.println(practice);
        return practice;
    }


}

@Service
class SoccerCoach implements Coach{

    public SoccerCoach() {

    }

    @Override
    public String workout() {
        String practice = "practice your footwork!";
        System.out.println(practice);
        return practice;
    }

}

@RestController
class MyController{

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello() {

        return "Time on server is: " + new java.util.Date();
    }

}
```

I tried autowiring the ApplicationContext object into the TennisCoach class. When I run this, that object is null.

*How do we retrieve beans in Boot?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach is to use the `@Autowired` annotation. Also, because you have two different implementations of the `Coach` interface, you should use the `@Qualifier` annotation to tell Spring which interface implementation to inject.

Some tutorials about these two annotations, to get you started:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

For your example, to inject the beans into your controller, you should do:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("soccerCoach")
    private Coach coach;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello() {
        // this should invoke the workout() from SoccerCoach implementation
        System.out.println(coach.workout());

        return "Time on server is: " + new java.util.Date();
    }

}
```

Or, to inject the `soccerCoach` into the `tennisCoach` as you intended, using constructor injection , the code would become:

```
@Service
class TennisCoach implements Coach {

    private Coach soccerCoach;

    @Autowired
    public TennisCoach(@Qualifier("soccerCoach") Coach soccerCoach) {
        this.soccerCoach = soccerCoach;
    }

    public Coach getCoach() {
        System.out.println(soccerCoach.getClass());

        return soccerCoach;
    }

}
```

If you really need to use the `ApplicationContext` to retrieve some bean, it's not advisable to do so in your class that has the `main` function. Just create another bean (you could use the `@Componenent` annotation). Here's an example:

```
@Component
public class AnyComponent {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void invokeCoach() {
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean("tennisCoach"));
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean(SoccerCoach.class));
    }

}
```

And inject this bean in your application flow, could be in the controller, service, or repository:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private AnyComponent anyComponent;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello() {
        anyComponent.invokeCoach();

        return "Time on server is: " + new java.util.Date();
    }

}
```

Note: Injecting beans through annotation is something specific to Spring, in general, not Spring Boot in particular.

From https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire:

> Starting with Spring 2.5, the framework introduced a new style of Dependency Injection driven by @Autowired Annotations. This annotation allows Spring to resolve and inject collaborating beans into your bean.

Comment: How would I do it without field injection? From what I've read, that is generally considered bad practice. How would I do it with constructor injection?

Comment: I've updated my answer to do that with constructor injection. Personally I like the field injection, but I think it's just a matter of preference. Also the `soccerCoach` could be final: `private final Coach soccerCoach;`

Comment: I understand, but both answers here are slightly missing the point. I do not understand _how_ to retrieve a bean. If you look at my code, in the main method, I am trying to instantiate a Tennis coach view the `new Coach()` process. However, I get a null pointer exception. Even after altering my code to be like your above, I am still getting a null pointer exception. How do I retrieve a bean from the Spring container?

Comment: It should be as you've tried, with ApplicationContext. In your main app, just do `context.getBean(TennisCoach.class)`. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088780/how-to-get-bean-using-application-context-in-spring-boot.

Comment: I've looked at that page and tried autowiring an applicationcontext. It just gets returned as null, doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Just to clarify things a bit, I've updated my example to include the `ApplicationContext`. It's not advisable to use it in the `main` function. Just create another bean where you inject it.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the required beans directly. No need of `ApplicationContext` in Spring boot.

```
@Service
class TennisCoach {

    private SoccerCoach soccerCoach;

    @Autowired
    public TennisCoach(SoccerCoach soccerCoach) {
      this.soccerCoach = soccerCoach;
    }

}
```

Comment: If your field is final and there is only one constructor, there is no need even for the `@Autowired` annotation. I typically use Lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to eliminate boilerplate.

Comment: How do I retrieve this bean though? `TennisCoach tCoach = new Coach();`? When I attempt to instantiate the object, It says I'm missing an argument.

Comment: No need to do that. The Spring container will take care of object instantiation.

Comment: Ok, but _how_ do I retrieve the bean if I do not do `new Coach()`? In my main method I am trying to retrieve the bean, and I cannot figure out how to do so.