# Is ApplicationContext automatically instantiated in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

Is ApplicationContext automatically instantiated in Spring?

If I have my bean defined like this

```
@Component
public class Car{
   ...
}
```

and then I have my config class which tells Spring container where to look for beans through the annotation @ComponentScan

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
   ...
}
```

Is Spring automatically creating a context loading all my beans? Or do I have to create it programmatically? If so how do I do it, with something like this?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {
   ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
   context.getBean(Car.class);
   ...
}
```

Even doing this, there may be a problem, because every time I need the context I have to call new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext...
what is the recommended way to instantiate the context and making him available inside the whole project, maybe as a bean like inside Spring boot app where i can just autowire it.

How Spring Boot can initialize it, load all the beans and let the context available as a bean, ready to be autowired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, Application Context isn't automatically instantiated, if you're having a simple and basic `Spring Core` application. Moreover, your `@Configuration` class won't scan anything and won't create any beans, if you don't create your Spring Container/Context explicitly with that @Configuration class.

There are several ways of creating Application Context, but the most popular and traditional ones are:

- `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(applicationContext.xml)` - implying, that you have your container configuration in the `applicationContext.xml` file;
- `ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigClass.class);` - implying, that your `ConfigClass` is the `@Configuration` class.

---

**However**, if you have the **Spring Boot** application annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, then the *Application Context* will be automatically instantiated for you, because:

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation [consists](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) of:

- `@EnableAutoConfiguration` - which enables Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism;
- `@ComponentScan` - which enable `@Component` scan on the package where the application is located;
- `@Configuration` - allows to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes.

and this will spin up the context for you.

You can obtain the reference to the Spring Context created by Spring Boot, by the factory method you have in your *main* method: `SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);`

This returns the reference to the Application Context and you can assign it to variable like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. That's what I thought. But I still don't know how to make available the context to the whole project. I mean after creating it through one of the way you suggested, how can i make it available as a bean like Spring Boot does?

Comment: You can simply let your class implement `ApplicationContextAware` and then autowire the context with `@Autowire ApplicationContext context` as a field in your class. You can also hold the reference returned by *run* method, somewhere, in the bean or just anywhere you wish. There are several ways. Also, please use upvote and accept when you find an answer helpful, instead of saying "thank you" texts.

Comment: I do not have run... cause I'm using Spring core. So I have to implement ApplicationContextAware every time I need the application context? this seems wired... how does Spring Boot does? With spring boot I can access the ApplicationContext by autowiring it without doing anything special... is Spring Boot using ApplicationContextAware under the hood?

Comment: I can't explain entire SpringBoot architecture in just a comment on Stackoverflow, but I gave you the minimum knowledge you need, in my answer. Why do you think, that implementing ApplicationContextAware is weird? that is a legal and popular way to achieve what you want. If you're using Spring MVC or Spring Boot, then it's not needed, because they come with pre-configured context.

Comment: Ok I found what I was looking for... thank you for your help! "in newer version it may be better to use annotations, rather than implementing spring-specific interfaces" found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553322/6783371