# What will happen if I tried to instantiate spring bean manually

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Reading some source code and I stumbled upon this spring bean

```
@Service
public class ValidationService {...}
```

Which is instantiated manually using the `new()` operator in many places

ex:
`var validationService=new ValidationService();`

Now I am thinking to refactor all of these instantiations and replace it with proper spring injection.

It made me think about what would happen if we instantiated a bean using the `new()` operator. Will it create a new instance of the bean or will it just retrieve the spring managed instance ?

Comment: If you're instantiating the object, it won't be a spring bean but a simple java object. It won't be managed by the spring container and you won't benefit from the advantages of spring. If you want to get a spring bean, you have to fetch it from the spring application context with `applicationContext.getBean("myBeanDefinition")`.
There are several ways to get access to the application context.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553322/7132739) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the object is instantiated manually, it acts like a normal Java object.

Spring is not involved, so all the "spring features" (Inversion of control, dependency injection, etc..) not available.